# Insufficient Privileges error when changing value of picklist

Tags: visualforce, controller, picklist, actionsupport

I have picklist of values `Lead` and `Opportunity`, By default value of picklist is `Lead`

When I change it to `Opportunity` and, if change it back to `Lead`, it gives error of Insufficient Privileges.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one of the objects is private. The user tries to edit one of the record but the other is read only or not shared. Therefore you will receive a "Insufficient Privileges" error message.